# What happens to old Object references?

Tags: java, object, reference

**Small Example**

```
Class Tree{
    private Leaf leaf;

    public Tree(Leaf leaf){  //passing a object that is instantiated outside the class
        this.leaf = leaf;       
    }

    public void foo(){
         Bush bush = new Bush(leaf);
    }

    public setLeaf(Leaf leaf){
        this.leaf = leaf;    
    }
}

class Forest{
    private Tree tree;

    public Forest(Tree tree){
        this.tree = tree;

    }     
    public void doSometing(){
        Leaf leaf = new Leaf();
        tree.setLeaf(leaf);
    }

}

//code to initialize objects described above
```

If I create a new `Leaf` node, and set it as the leaf of the Tree, I know this will update the pointer inside `Tree`.  My question is, what happens to the *old* `Leaf` object?

Comment: It will get garbage collected: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

Comment: What do you mean by "the old point of leaf remains dangling"? What exactly are you asking? It would really help if you could put a bit more effort into formatting your code before posting, btw. A well-intended piece of code is *radically* more readable than a badly-indented piece of code.

Comment: @JonSkeet with the old point , i mean the instance of leaf created before calling the doSomething() method.

Comment: And what do you mean by "dangling"? How much do you already understand about garbage collection in Java, and differentiating between references and objects?

Comment: @JonSkeet i have to improve well my own idea of the garbage collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is no Strong reference being held to the old leaf object in the code, then it is eligible for garbage collection and will be cleaned up by the Garbage Collector.

**Example 1 :**

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee("John Doe"):

emp1 = new Employee("John");  
// There is no strong reference to previously created Employee Object
// So its eligible for garbage collection
```

**Example 2  :**

```
 Employee emp1 = new Employee("John Doe"):
 emp2 = emp1;

 emp1 = new Employee("John");  
 // In this case emp2 hold a strong reference to previously created Object
 // so its not eleigible for Garbage collection
```

**Note :** A strong reference is a normal Java reference. For more info on different type of references refer the following article -[Java - types of references](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references)

Comment: for strong reference what do you mean?

Comment: There are different kind of references that can be held for a particular object. A  strong reference is an ordinary Java reference. Read this article for more info - https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references

Comment: can you see question update?, in this case i made a strong reference to object leaf, and it can't be deleted by garbage collector, right? @Kakarot.

Comment: the line is the function `foo()`.

Comment: NOw you are storing a reference to entire Tree in function foo() so its not holding a strong refernce to leaf yet

Comment: i made a mistake, just fixed.look @Kakarot.

Comment: Yes i this case leaf wont be garbage collected unless even bush loses the strong reference